# Showing the Quiz Score for the current user of current quiz attempt?

Tags: views, users, quiz

I am trying to create a block using Views which shows the current users score for the current attempt of the quiz being completed by the user. The idea here the student can see their overall score while working through the questions; and as they get each question right their score updates from question to question.

I have been playing around with the contextual filters and relationships but I cannot seem to work out how to filter it down to only show the current user's score of the current quiz attempt. Any suggestions on this?